# JsStore Constructor Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, service-worker, office-js-store

so I get an error on my console when importing and calling the JsStore library object from within a service worker.

```
importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore@3.0.0/dist/jsstore.min.js');
importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore@3.0.0/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js');


var connection = new JsStore.Connection();

console.log(connection);
```

This gives a console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: JsStore is not a constructor

[Documentation](https://jsstore.net/tutorial/connection/) which I followed.

Answer (score 0):

This was as a result of using the Versioned scripts @3.0.0. I used the latest scripts as below:

- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore/dist/jsstore.min.js
- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js

and it worked.